# how can i save videos in webm format instead of mkv format

Tags: javascript, php, webm, mkv, web-mediarecorder

I need a help. I have a javascript code in my site that record videos and save them on the server. The format in which the videos are saved depends on the browser I am using, because if I use Opera or Chrome, the videos are saved in MKV format, if I use Firefox instead, the videos are saved in WEBM format. The problem is that the videos I save using Opera and Chrome (i.e. MKV) Firefox cannot read them, while Opera and Chrome read the WEBM videos generated with firefox without problems.
How can I make Opera and Chrome also save videos in WEBM so I no longer have the problem?
JavaScript code:

```
let constraintObj = { 
    audio: true, 
    video: { 
        facingMode: "user", 
        width: { min: 640, ideal: 1280, max: 1920 },
        height: { min: 480, ideal: 720, max: 1080 } 
    } 
}; 
// width: 1280, height: 720  -- preference only
// facingMode: {exact: "user"}
// facingMode: "environment"

//handle older browsers that might implement getUserMedia in some way
if (navigator.mediaDevices === undefined) {
    navigator.mediaDevices = {};
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia = function(constraintObj) {
        let getUserMedia = navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia;
        if (!getUserMedia) {
            return Promise.reject(new Error('getUserMedia is not implemented in this browser'));
        }
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            getUserMedia.call(navigator, constraintObj, resolve, reject);
        });
    }
}else{
    navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices()
    .then(devices => {
        devices.forEach(device=>{
            console.log(device.kind.toUpperCase(), device.label);
            //, device.deviceId
        })
    })
    .catch(err=>{
        console.log(err.name, err.message);
    })
}

navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraintObj)
.then(function(mediaStreamObj) {
    //connect the media stream to the first video element
    let video = document.querySelector('video');
    if ("srcObject" in video) {
        video.srcObject = mediaStreamObj;
    } else {
        //old version
        video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(mediaStreamObj);
    }
    
    video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
        //show in the video element what is being captured by the webcam
        video.play();
    };
    
    //add listeners for saving video/audio
    let start = document.getElementById('btnStart');
    let stop = document.getElementById('btnStop');
    let save = document.getElementById('btnSave');
    let vidSave = document.getElementById('vid2');
    let mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(mediaStreamObj);
    let chunks = [];
    var blob = null;
    document.getElementById("vid2").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("btnSave").style.visibility = "hidden";
    
    var contatore=0;
    var dontstop=0;
    

    save.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
        
     contatore = 0;
    const formData = new FormData();
     formData.append('video', blob);
     fetch('videoRec', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
        })
        .then(response => { console.log('upload success, ');
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML="Video salvato con successo, ";
        })
    .catch(error => {console.log('error');
        document.getElementById('response').innerHTML="Errore durante il caricamento del video. Riprova.";
    })
    
    });

    
    start.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
        
        dontstop=1;
        //if user already started video before, ask him if want to save that video before 
        //recording another video
        if(contatore!=0){
            var domanda=confirm("Il video appena registrato andrà eliminato. Vuoi Procedere?");
            if (domanda === false) {
            exit;
            }    
        }

        //when user's recording, vid2 must be hidden
        if(document.getElementById("vid2").style.visibility=="visible"){
            document.getElementById("vid2").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById("btnSave").style.visibility="hidden";
            document.getElementById('response').innerHTML=" ";
        }

        //start recording
        mediaRecorder.start();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

        //disable start button and enable stop button
        document.getElementById('btnStart').disabled=true;
        document.getElementById('btnStop').disabled=false;

        //contatore increments when user records, so if he starts another rec without stopping before
        //ask him if want to save the last video
        contatore++;
        var timeleft = 5; //video must be 120 seconds

        downloadTimer = setInterval(function(){
        if(timeleft <= 0){ 

            //after 120 seconds record will stops automatically
            clearInterval(downloadTimer); //the countdown disappared
            document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
            mediaRecorder.stop();
            console.log(mediaRecorder.state);

            document.getElementById('btnStart').disabled=false;
            document.getElementById('btnStop').disabled=true;


            video.onloadedmetadata = function(ev) {
        
            chunks.push(ev.data);
            };

            
            // vid2 appears
            document.getElementById("vid2").style.visibility = "visible";
            document.getElementById("btnSave").style.visibility = "visible";
             blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm;' });
            chunks = [];
            let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            vidSave.src = videoURL;
            

            } else {
                //else countdown continues
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = timeleft + " seconds remaining";
            }
        timeleft -= 1;
        }, 1000)
                     
    })

    stop.addEventListener('click', (ev)=>{
        if(dontstop!=1){
            exit;
        }
        mediaRecorder.stop();
        console.log(mediaRecorder.state);
        document.getElementById('btnStart').disabled=false;
        document.getElementById('btnStop').disabled=true;
        clearInterval(downloadTimer);
        document.getElementById("countdown").innerHTML = "Finished";
        document.getElementById("vid2").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("btnSave").style.visibility = "visible";
    });
    mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = function(ev) {
        chunks.push(ev.data);
    }
    mediaRecorder.onstop = (ev)=>{
        blob = new Blob(chunks, { 'type' : 'video/webm;' });
        chunks = [];
        let videoURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        vidSave.src = videoURL;
        
    } 
})
.catch(function(err) { 
    console.log(err.name, err.message); 
});
```

Thank you very much!
Gennaro

Comment: Likely you are mistaken. The format from what code you have provided depends on tthe format provided by the server. Possibly different browsers, the server detects which format to serve ... Ok forget i said that. Could it be instead the mkv sites you reference (without links) are blocking your hacks/requests?

Comment: Hello GetSet! thanks for answer me. I'm sorry but I didn't understand what you said. I pass to the server webm format through javaScript code but when I use Chrome or Opera, the videos are saved in mkv. the site is in local on my pc not yet online

Comment: I have exactly the same problem with latest chrome version on mac (but not on windows). It worked correctly some months ago.
I think it's a chromium bug, certainly related to this one: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=980822

Answer (score 1):

you can try to fix the mimetype to `video/webm;codecs=VP8`, it should work with any browser supporting MediaRecorder